# Display text as a header in flatlist items to seperate each part, React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist that renders data fetched from the DB,so i made sure the items are sorted by type.

[image]

Now i want to render a text at the top of each part to make a distinction between every part, a header sort of(example: Specialities: and then the part of specialities, doctor: and then the part of doctors)
here is a look at my code:

```
<FlatList
            data={this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.type === 'spécialité' ? -1 : 1)}
            keyExtractor={item => { return item.id }}
            renderItem={({ item }) => 
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>NavigationService.navigate('Où ?',{lien: item.lien, choix: c}) }> 
              {item.type == 'spécialité' && (
                
                <Highlighter
                  highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFC617' }}
                  searchWords={[this.searchedText]}
                  textToHighlight={item.name}
                  style={{paddingLeft:10,color: '#2c3e50',height:42,backgroundColor: 'white'}}
                />
                
              )}
              {item.type == 'Tag' && (
                <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFC617' }}
                searchWords={[this.searchedText]}
                textToHighlight={item.name}
                style={{paddingLeft:10,color: '#2c3e50',height:42,backgroundColor: 'white'}}
              />
                
              )}
              {item.type == 'Médecin' && (
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flexDirection: 'row',flexWrap: 'wrap',height:80 }}>
                <Image style={{ height: 50, width: 80,marginTop:5, borderRadius:5 }} source={{ uri:getImageFromApi( item.image ) }} />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',color:'#2980b9' }}> {item.name} </Text>
                <Text style={{color: '#2c3e50'}}> {item.speciality} </Text>
                </View>
              </View>)}
              {item.type == 'Clinique' && (
                
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flexDirection: 'row',flexWrap: 'wrap',height:80 }}>
                <Image style={{ height: 50, width: 80,marginTop:5, borderRadius:5 }} source={{ uri:getImageFromApi( item.image ) }} />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',color:'#2980b9' }}> {item.name} </Text>
                <Text style={{color: '#2c3e50'}}> {item.speciality} </Text>
                </View>
              </View>)}
              
            </TouchableOpacity>}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />)}
```

i tried doing <Text in my touchable opacity but it duplicates inside every item.
I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent and show a text or even render a custom component.

```
 <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ListHeaderComponent={()=><Text>1231312</Text>}
        ListFooterComponent={()=><Text>1231312</Text>}
      />
```

Or if you want to have group level headers consider using the section list

```
<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
    <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but there is 4 different part in render item sorted by type as you can see in the code, how can i render a header at the top of every part, not just one header for all the items?

Comment: Why not use a section list instead of a flatlist ? as you need a grouped view

Comment: I m new to react native i didn't knew of this component, it seems like the right answer.thank you trying it right now!

Comment: If you need anything please be free to ask

Comment: ok thank you, i replace it and got another issue undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.length') sectionlist. is there a way to keep my flatlist and do the seperators?

Comment: Flatist is more of a list of items of the same type so there is no easy way,  so section list is the easiest option, may i know where you are getting the error from ?

Comment: check the docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist.html, you will have to provide the data in a grouped way, thats why you are getting the error

Comment: its maybe from the data i fetch from the server but i got no control over it. this is the problem,i 'm only on the front-end side. see my code above, i changed flatlist to sectionlist

Comment: Why not do the grouping at front end and show it in section list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `ListHeaderComponent` prop

Read the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent)

An example would be like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ListHeaderComponent={() => {
      return (<Text>Header</Text>)
    }}
 />
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but there is 4 different part in render item sorted by type as you can see in the code, how can i render a header at the top of every part, not just one header for all the items?